# How to get all only one value from a partially duplicated row?

Tags: r

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

my.data = data.table(
  participant.index = c(1,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,7),
  repeat.instance = c(1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1),
  gender = c("male", "female", "male", "male", "female", "male", "male" ,"male" ,"male"),
  type.procedure = c("percut", "percut", "percut", "open", "open", "open", "open", "open", "open"),
  suture.used = c("prolene", "vicryl", "silk", "prolene", "prolene", "vicryl","silk", "vicryl","prolene")
)
```

If we look at this data, we can see that for participant.index 5, repeat.instance 1, is repeated because two different suture material were used in the same procedure. I want all the suture.used for one procedure in one row, but only one observation per column. I am not understanding how do I do that. If I use drop duplicates, the data on second suture material used will be lost. Could you anyone over here help me with this?

Comment: Can you clarify what your end result would look like? A "tidy" approach may include a new column added indicating the "number" of `suture.used` which could have values of 1 and 2 for those two rows to retain all data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
my.data[, .(sutures.used = list(suture.used)), by=.(participant.index, repeat.instance, gender, type.procedure)]
```

Output:

```
   participant.index repeat.instance gender type.procedure sutures.used
1:                 1               1   male         percut      prolene
2:                 2               1 female         percut       vicryl
3:                 3               1   male         percut         silk
4:                 3               2   male           open      prolene
5:                 4               1 female           open      prolene
6:                 5               1   male           open  vicryl,silk
7:                 6               1   male           open       vicryl
8:                 7               1   male           open      prolene
```

Alternatively, you could also create columns for the additional suture:

```
dcast(my.data[, id:=paste0("suture",1:.N), by=.(participant.index,repeat.instance)],
      ...~id, value.var = "suture.used")
```

Output:

```
   participant.index repeat.instance gender type.procedure suture1 suture2
1:                 1               1   male         percut prolene    <NA>
2:                 2               1 female         percut  vicryl    <NA>
3:                 3               1   male         percut    silk    <NA>
4:                 3               2   male           open prolene    <NA>
5:                 4               1 female           open prolene    <NA>
6:                 5               1   male           open  vicryl    silk
7:                 6               1   male           open  vicryl    <NA>
8:                 7               1   male           open prolene    <NA>
```